# ¿Como modificar la estructura de una tabla con sequelize sin borrar los datos?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, base-de-datos, sequelize.js

Tengo una modelo hecho con **sequelize**, no puedo borrar los datos de la tabla **institucion**, pero ahora debo añadirle un campo **jornada**.

Ya probé `sequelize.sync` pero no modifica la estructura de la tabla.
y sequelize.sync({force:true}) borraria todos los datos.

Es importante que no borre nada ya que es una base de datos que a medida que el proyecto cresca debe ir modificandoce.

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar `alter: true` en lugar de `force`? La opción más recomendada es usar migraciones como te dice @yeinel, pero para crear una columna creo *alter* te sirve. En caso alteres una columna **ya existente**, entonces sí es poco recomendable debido a que borrará los datos de dicha columna.

Comment: Si, ya lo probé pero me aparecía un error con un tipo enum.

Comment: ¿Qué error es ese? Es bueno que pongas estos detalles en la pregunta porque pueden ser útiles.

Comment: que en otra tabla yo uso un tipo enum... y cuando use sync con alter true, trataba de sobreescribir el tipo enum de la otra tabla y eso causaba el error. en definitiva el alter true, se utiliza mas bien para añadir tablas al modelo... pero no me sirve para modificar una que ya tenga datos ingresados...

Comment: No se utiliza solo para eso, de hecho, desde la versión [4.0](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html) se añadió soporte para `ALTER TABLE`. Ver [`sequelize#sync`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-sync).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando migraciones es la manera más recomendada si estás en producción. Para realizar una migración simplemente necesitas escribir un archivo que exporte un objeto con dos funciones:

- up: transforma el estado actual de los modelos.
- down: revierte alguna funcionalidad específica.

> **Nota:** este fichero debe estar en el directorio *migrations* en la raíz del proyecto.

Estas funciones reciben como parámetro un objeto de tipo `QueryInterface` y una instancia de Sequelize. Para realizar cualquier tipo de cambio te interesa hacerlo en la función *up*.

Para cambiar un tipo de columna basta utilizar el método `changeColumn`:

```
module.exports = {
  up(queryInterface, sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.changeColumn('nombreModelo', 'nombreAtributo', {
      type: sequelize.<nuevo tipo>,
      // otros cambios
    });
  },
};
```

Finalmente debes hacer uso del CLI para correr tu migración:

> **Nota:** instala el paquete [sequelize-cli](https://npmjs.com/package/sequelize-cli) si aún no lo tienes.

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

Cuando termine el proceso, tu columna ya debe estar migrada. Como recomendación final, [consultar la documentación](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html).

Answer (score 1):

El problema que planteas (un modelo de datos que evoluciona) es algo comun. La solucion que uso en estos casos es crear [migraciones](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/migrations/).

Saludos

Comment: Me podrias ayudar un poco mas con eso?

Comment: si me das un ejemplo de modificacion te puedo dar un ejemplo de migracion que haga esa modificacion. saludos

Comment: Gracias. 
En que te lo puedo enviar?

Basicamente es añadir un campo a una columna que ya tiene datos ingresados. Y si puedes tambien el como seria si voy a agregar tablas a la db?